# Checking if Visual c++ redistribute pack version 2010 is installed on a machine using vb\c# .net

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net

I was looking for a programmatic solution for this.

I found some articles with registry keys, but I would like to see if someone has a graceful way to check whether this is installed or not, and if so, which version, 64 or 32 bit.

Comment: Why would you not want to use the registry? I do not understand what you mean by "graceful". If you try and look for files you will need admin rights, and just because the files exist doesn't mean it's installed

Comment: I have not yet found a solution that avoids reading the registry. This [answer I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543347/10871073) will outline the code required to check *via* the registry; it doesn't involve that much effort.

Comment: Give this a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379143/check-if-application-is-installed-in-registry

Comment: [Using Windows Installer to Inventory Products and Patches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/inventory-products-and-patches-) -- [MsiEnumProducts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/nf-msi-msienumproductsw) function: much faster than WMI's `Win32_Product`, slower than direct Registry lookups.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, please edit your question and tags to focus on a single programming language.

Comment: Could you please, at least share those solutions, so we don't repeat it and waste your time ?