# Visual Studio 2022 Installer not Bundling VC++ Redistributable

Tags: c#, visual-c++, setup-project

We have a C# application using a C++ wrapper DLL class in a C++ project.

When we created the setup/msi and installed it, the application is not running, as the necessary files referenced by the Visual Studio include directory are missing with the installation.

Comment: Did you *tell* the installer project that the VC++ Redis was a dependency?

Comment: How to do that, pls explain

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097193/can-i-bundle-the-visual-studio-2015-c-redistributable-dlls-with-my-applicatio

Comment: Hi Hans - I am using visual studio 2022 community edition. Not visual studio 2015. I do not see any DLL in redist folder

Comment: Are you using the "Installer Projects" extension to create your .msi file? If so, do you have the project set to *also* create a "Setup.exe" file? Please add these details to your question and I *might* be able to offer a clear answer for you.

Comment: A typical path (my VS2022 is old) is C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.30.30704\x86\Microsoft.VC143.CRT

Comment: The files are called "vc_redist.XXX.exe", where "XXX" is "x64", "x86" or "arm64", for each supported platform.

Comment: Adrian- are you suggesting to copy paste exe (since our project is x86) to the installer applications folder

Comment: Maybe. It depends on how you build your installer. If you can clarify the points I highlighted in my **second** comment, I can give you a quick solution (maybe) that doesn't involve copying those redis files, or link you to [one of my older answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59543347/10871073) that explains how you can use the copy method.

Comment: I know that a number of 'commercial' applications I have on my PC include one or more VC Redist files in their install locations.

Comment: The "Setup.exe" file can be made to install any pre-requisites (like .NET frameworks and VC++ redistributables).

Comment: Yes, I am creating setup.exe. Struggling to get it run on a computer without visual studio installed. It is running fine with computers on visual studio is installed. It runs fine if the c++ part is comented. It has c# part running fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" extension, then you can 'instruct' the "Setup.exe" file you create to download and install the VC++ Redistributable (if required) before it runs the actual ".msi" installer package.

You do this by specifying that redistributable as a "prerequisite". Right-click on the installer project in the Solution Explorer pane and select the "Properties" command; then, in the pop-up displayed, click the "Prerequisites..." button. You will see another pop-up, like below:

[image]

Be sure that the "Create setup program..." box is checked, then scroll down the  list box to (near) the bottom and check the relevant "Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries" package for your target platform.

With this setting, the generated "Setup.exe" file will then verify if an installation or update of the redistributable is needed and, if so, will manage its download and installation from the selected website. (Note that the redistributables are the same for all versions of Visual Studio since v.14, so it will be valid for VS 2022.)

Comment: Thanks Adrian- working fine. We used merge package

Comment: Hi Adrian- one more help, in order to run this application I have to install “windows SDK for UWP managed Apps” on client machine, any idea why this is required? any way to get rid of this?

Comment: @Razack Hmm. Does your C# part require any sort of *compilation* of the C++ part(s)? If so, then I guess the SDK would be needed.

Comment: C# part does not require any c++ compilation. If yes how to disable this

Comment: @Razack I don't make UWP apps but - maybe - you need to install the [UWP Desktop Runtime Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=102159) on the target machines? Not sure exactly how to go about doing that but maybe there's a merge module for it? I guess installing the UWP SDK will also set up the DLLs that the runtime package has.